# Error when using FaceBook Registration form

Tags: facebook

I tries to use facebook registration plugin but I got this error

```
'redirect_uri' should be an absolute url.
```

and here is the code :

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>My Facebook Registration Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
      </script>
      <script>
         FB.init({ 
            appId:'125309184237777', cookie:true, 
            status:true, xfbml:true 
         });
      </script>
         <fb:registration
            fields="[{'name':'name'}, {'name':'email'},
            {'name':'favorite_car','description':'What is your favorite car?',
            'type':'text'}]" redirect-uri="index.php">
    </fb:registration>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put in an absolute URL in for the redirect-uri.  For example, http://example.com/index.php